# display modal nested within panel

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am using Bootstrap and react to show a panel component, which has inside it a modal:

```
<div className="panel panel-default" id="content">
   <div className='panel-heading text-center' id='tableButtons'>
      <h2 className="panel-title central-headingText">Assignments </h2>
   </div>
   <Table/>
</div>
```

Where `<Table/>` is:

```
        <div>
            <div id='tableContainer'>
                <table className="table table-condensed"></table>
            </div>

            {this.state.displayDeleteModal
                ?
                <div id="myModal" className="modal fade" role="dialog">
                    <div className="modal-dialog">

                    <div className="modal-content">
                      <div className="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                      </div>
                      <div className="modal-body">
                        <p>Are you sure you want to make the deletion?</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                  </div>
                </div>
                :
                null
            }

        </div>
```

However, when the variable `this.state.displayDeleteModal` becomes true, the modal is not displayed.
I believe this is because the modal is nested within a Bootstrap `panel`.

How can I make the modal appear?

Comment: where is the code, that triggers modal's visibility? some click or button, because, by default, modal isn't visible, or are you firing modal's show event on `this.state.displayDeleteModal` becoming true

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: In order to make the modal visible, I am making `this.state.displayDeleteModal` true.

Answer (score 1):

You need to manually opens a modal on your condition.

To show modal using JavaScript use

```
$('#myModal').modal('show')
```

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-options

Try this code:

```
    <div>
        <div id='tableContainer'>
            <table className="table table-condensed"></table>
        </div>

        {this.state.displayDeleteModal
            ?
            <div id="myModal" className="modal fade" role="dialog">
                <div className="modal-dialog">

                <div className="modal-content">
                  <div className="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                  </div>
                  <div className="modal-body">
                    <p>Are you sure you want to make the deletion?</p>
                  </div>
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
            <script>
                $(function(){
                   $('#myModal').modal('show');
                });
            </script>  
            :
            null
        }

    </div>
```

Comment: I added the code `<script>
                        {$(function(){
                            $('#myModal').modal('show');
                        });}
                    </script>` but I am getting an error on that line: `Adjacent elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag while parsing file`.

Comment: Also, how do I call that JQuerry function?